# JRebel - sync new gradle jars on classpath

Tags: jrebel

Can jrebel detect a jar file has been added to maven/gradle and then automatically add it my libs folder and add it to the classpath?

For example I'm running IntelliJ and Jetty and I make a gradle change to add a new version of a jar dependency and then click "gradle refresh."

Can jrebel be set up to load that jar? Otherwise this requires a full restart which partially makes jrebel less useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

JRebel works by reloading individual class files, but not whole JARs.
If you add a new dependency or update the version of an existing dependency then it won't get reloaded.

However, if this library you're updating or adding is your own internal library that you build yourself, then it is possible to reload the changes.

In that case you need to build a *rebel.xml* file into the root of that library jar and configure it to point to the build directory of the library.

Comment: yeah seems correct. pity, that'd be a nice situation to not have to restart the server